# The next Error with bibliography shows; "I'm skipping whatever remains of this command The style file: abbrv.bst Database file #1: biblio.bib"

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

I have some error in my bibliography, this is the error that shows when I compile the ".bib" archive:

```
 -line 8 of file articulo.aux
 : \citation{*
 :            }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
The style file: abbrv.bst
Database file #1: biblio.bib
```

In my document is very important the numbering in bibliography. For this I used the bibliogrphy style abbrv. How is shown in the principal code:

```
\documentclass[5p,times,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}    
\addto\captionsspanish{
\def\tablename{Tabla}
}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   
\usepackage{amsmath}          
\usepackage{epstopdf}          
\usepackage{flushend}           
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{xcolor}% paquete añadido para color en mathmode
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}%paquete añadido para cancelar terminos con slash(/)
\usepackage{enumitem} %Para cambier formato de items en itemize
% declarations for front matter
\usepackage{caption} % Para generar Caption con el nombre de "fig"
\usepackage{comment}


\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\begin{frontmatter}
\end{frontmatter}
\cite{david} 
\nocite{*}
\cite{coalmining}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliografia}
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```

The code of the .bib file is the next one

```
@book{david,
Author = {Angulo García, David and Olivar Tost, Gerard},
Publisher = {Manizales, 2012.},
Title = {Esquemas de Desarrollo Sostenible : una Aplicación de Redes Complejas a la Región de Caldas = Sustainable development schemes: [recurso electrónico].},
URL = {http://ezproxy.unal.edu.co/login?url=http://search.ebscohost.com/login.aspx?direct=true&db=cat02704a&AN=unc.000723149&lang=es&site=eds-live},
Year = {2012},
}

@article{coalmining,
 author = {Min and Zhou and Bang-jun and Wang and Feng, Ji},
 issn = {1878-5220},
 journal = {Procedia Earth and Planetary Science},
 number = {special issue title: Proceedings of the International Conference on Mining 
 science and Technology (ICMST2009)},
 pages = {1737 - 1743},
 title = {The 6th International Conference on Mining Science and Technology: Coalmining 
 cities' economic growth mechanism and sustainable development analysis based on logistic 
 dynamics model.},
 Volume = {1},
 Year = {2009},
}

@book{pezzey37,
  title={Economic analysis of sustainable growth and sustainable development.},
  author={Pezzey, John and Rusong, W and Hinman, GW and Ruitenbeek, HJ and Kairiukstis, L 
and Buracas, A and Straszak, A and Altieri, MA and Archibugi, F and Nijkamp, D and 
others},
 year={1990},
 publisher={Banco Mundial, Washington, DC (EUA).},
}
@misc{ourfuture51,
  title={Our common future. By World commission on environment and development.(London, 
Oxford University Press, 1987, pp. 383},
  author={Butlin, John},
  year={1989},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library},
}
```

How could I fix this?

Comment: Holà. Do you have any citation commands in your actual code? We would need to see an MWE that produces the error you are describing on your machine. Make a test directory, test document, paste above code, edit until it produces the error, copy there, paste here. Actually, I just realized you should know how that works; after all, you have 358 reputation ;)

Comment: The error says: "I found no `\citation` commands". And indeed, your example has no citations in it. Do you still get the error if you if you add `\nocite{*}` (or `\cite{david}`) in your main document?

Comment: Does [Question mark instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852) help?

Comment: Off-topic: The `subfigure` package is deprecated. Since you're also loading the `caption` package, you should be loading `subcaption` instead of `subfigure`.

Comment: @thymaro I added a citation command in the actual code, and the error change a little but is still present.

Comment: @David Purton I added \nocite{*} command and the error that is shown is now in the post.

Comment: Does that exact code produce the error you report when you copy-paste compile it to a clean file in a clean directory?

Comment: You didn't give enough error context. The previous line says that you used `\nocite{*}` multiple times. Remove one and that error goes away. But you will still get a `natbib` error.

Comment: Two problems. First, the `authoryear` option of `elsarticle` is not compatible with the `abbrv` bibliography style. If you want author year citations, try `bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}`. Secondly, you need to put your URL inside `\url{}` and add `usepackage{url}` otherwise LaTeX will complain about the & characters (among other things) in your URL.

Comment: @David Purton if I change the "abbrv" to "elsarticle-harv" style, the numbering of bibliography in my document won't be shown, and I need the numbering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution for you.

Changes made:

- tidy up bibliography data a bit
- load `url` package
- use `bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}`
- remove duplicate `\nocite{*}`

MWE:

```
\documentclass[5p,times,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{david,
  author = {Angulo García, David and Olivar Tost, Gerard},
  publisher = {Manizales},
  title = {Esquemas de Desarrollo Sostenible: una Aplicación de Redes Complejas a la Región de Caldas = Sustainable development schemes: [recurso electrónico]},
  url = {http://ezproxy.unal.edu.co/login?url=http://search.ebscohost.com/login.aspx?direct=true&db=cat02704a&AN=unc.000723149&lang=es&site=eds-live},
  year = {2012},
}
@article{coalmining,
 author = {Min and Zhou and Bang-jun and Wang and Feng, Ji},
 issn = {1878-5220},
 journal = {Procedia Earth and Planetary Science},
 number = {special issue title: Proceedings of the International Conference on Mining science and Technology [ICMST2009]},
 pages = {1737-1743},
 title = {The 6th International Conference on Mining Science and Technology: Coalmining cities' economic growth mechanism and sustainable development analysis based on logistic dynamics model},
 Volume = {1},
 Year = {2009},
}
@book{pezzey37,
  title={Economic analysis of sustainable growth and sustainable development},
  author={Pezzey, John and Rusong, W and Hinman, GW and Ruitenbeek, HJ and Kairiukstis, L and Buracas, A and Straszak, A and Altieri, MA and Archibugi, F and Nijkamp, D and others},
  year={1990},
  publisher={Banco Mundial},
  address={Washington, DC},
}
@misc{ourfuture51,
  title={Our common future. By World commission on environment and development},
  author={Butlin, John},
  year={1989},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library},
}
\end{filecontents}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\cite{david} 
\cite{coalmining}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: with this sugestions the numbering dissapear. In my document is very important the numbering in bibliography. For this I used the bibliogrphy style abbrv. If you change this style you change the numbering. How to fix the number problem?. I need to use a .bib archive for simplify my document. Not to put the bibliography in the main document.

Comment: Now I'm confused as to what style you want for citations and references. Do you want numbered citations [1] and numbered references? Or do you want *author, year* citations with numbered references?

Comment: @JuanMuñoz If you just want numbered style everywhere, then simply remove the `authoryear` option from the `elsarticle` class. (This is what your original error told you to do.) Then you can happily use the `abbrv` bibliography style (or `elsarticle-num` or `elsarticle-num-names`).

Comment: How I can remove the authoryear option from the elsarticle class

Comment: @JuanMuñoz, use `\documentclass[5p,times]{elsarticle}` instead of `\documentclass[5p,times,authoryear]{elsarticle}`.